# Уменьшительная форма от слова "какао"

Tags: словообразование

Попалась в сети забавная фотография. Но и заставила задуматься: а можно ли как-то образовать уменьшительную форму от слова "какао" и, если да, то как?

[image]

Comment: Мне  кажется,  что  приемлемая  уменьшительная  форма  для  "какао"  в  русском  языке  отсутствует.

Comment: Лишь бы не так: http://gomazkov.livejournal.com/85104.html :)

Comment: Это точно. Отсутствует форма, и - ладушки.

Answer (score 1):

Какаушка, какавушка - слыхивано с детства. Мне нравится.
За отсутствием регулярной форму вполне можно использовать.
(+)
Да, думаю "какавушка" вернее будет орфографически.
Образовано от просторечной формы "какава".

Comment: "Какава" в детском лексиконе есть. "Какавушки" не слышала.

Answer (score 1):

Схема образования слова: какао - кака/ушк/о (с усечением основы исходного существительного).

Вообще говоря, для образования сущ. ср.рода  используются суффиксы ЫШК/ЮШК (солнце - солнышко, поле-полюшко), но можно добавить  суффикс УШК тоже (правда, он обычно применяется для образования сущ. ж.р.).

Кстати, у "пальто", кроме "пальтишко,  есть еще форма "пальтушка" с суффиксом УШК, но уже ж. рода. Схема: пальто - пальт/ушк/а.  Вот и примеры имеются:

К пальто не прикасайся, а его производное ― пальтишко, пальтушка резвятся по всем падежам наравне с зипунишком и кофтешкой (П. П. Бажов)

Пробовала притушить Нюра этот горький задышливый выкрик, в котором уже не было слезы, да только где там, живо взыграла девка, развернулась на стоптанных пятках и ускочила прочь, только пальтушка завилась меж ног (Владимир Личутин).

Answer (score 0):

От несклоняемых существительных уменьшительно-ласкательные формы образуются очень редко, например: пальто - пальтишко, суффикс ИШК.

В некоторых случаях используется суффикс ШК, но образованные при этом слова относятся к  разговорному или просторечному стилю: кино - киношка, такси - таксишка.

Приведенный вариант слова вряд ли можно увидеть в словаре, но для решения поставленной задачи он наиболее приемлем. В качестве альтернативы можно привести вариант "какаошко",но  он менее симпатичен и в записи, и в произношении. Поэтому мы имеем: какао - какаушко, суффикс ШК, чередование О/У в основе.

Comment: Но  слово-то  всё-равно  уродливое.

Comment: *Машина сломалась, целый день на* ***метрушке*** *катался.*